# Compare all file sizes of 2 directories in bash

Tags: bash, file, diff, size, directory

Sometimes it happens that for some reason the process of copying many files (i.e. to external HDD; using Nautilus file manager) crashes. If I then start it again, I use to ignore already existing files, though some of them were not copied 100%. So the properties window shows me "460 Files (225 GB)" in source folder and "460 Files (222 GB)" in destination folder...

How do I now find out which files have only been copied partially (maybe using `ls` and `diff`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `rsync` available, that works just fine between two local directories.

Comment: +1.   This is definately the way to sync directories, it'll be a lot faster than anything you can do with shell scripts.

Comment: Not the answer for that question, but the best one :-) I used rsync one or two times before but didn't think it's that much better than just cp'ing...

Comment: Sometimes "don't beat yourself over the head with the wrong tool" is the answer to the question.  :-)

Comment: Great answer to the OP, but I found this question because I want to diff file sizes

Answer (score 2):

```
for f1 in dir1/*
do
    f2="dir2/${f##*/}"
    if [[ $(sum "$f1") != $(sum "$f2") ]]
    then
        printf 'File %s does not match %s\n' "$f1" "$f2"
    fi
done
```

Or you could use this as your test:

```
    if ! diff -q "$f1" $f2" >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

i modified dennis' code. it compares file sizes. Faster but not safer then comparing checksums..

```
source=/???
target=/???


for i in "$source"/*
do
 f1=`stat -c%s $i`
 f2=`stat -c%s $target/${i##*/}`
  if [ "$f1" = "$f2" ]; then
        echo "$i" "$f1" VS "$target/${i##*/}" "$f2" "====>>>" "OK"
  else
        echo "$i" "$f1" VS "$target/${i##*/}" "$f2" "====>>>" "BAD"
  fi
done
```

Comment: If you have `stat` available. Also, you should use `$()` instead of backticks. Also, one set of quotes is sufficient for each `echo` statement. Why did you break them up that way?

Comment: that wouldn't work for subdirectories, would it..? because my folder contains many subfolders with other subfolders etc. so I think it's better done with `find` (?)

Comment: yeah won't work for subdirectories. Should have written that.